# Como instalar myqsl_xdevapi para php en W10?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, api

he buscado por todos lados pero cuanto mas busco mas me confundo y no entiendo como instalar todo lo necesario para poder usar la xdevapi de mysql en PHP, puede alguien orientarme?

Estoy leyendo este manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysql-xdevapi.installation.html y el enlace de descarga no se si esta mal o que porque me lleva a https://pecl.php.net/package/apc en vez de a https://pecl.php.net/package/mysql_xdevapi que creo que es el enlace correcto.

Uso Windows 10 64 bits y tengo instalado Apache(httpd-2.4.33-win64-VC15), PHP7(php-7.2.6-Win32-VC15-x64) y Mysql8 (mysql-installer-community-8.0.11.0), todo está bien configurado.

De todo lo que leí lo que no entendí bien es si para añadir extensiones de php en Windows hay que instalar PECL, y tampoco encontré información sobre como  instalar PECL o PEAR en Windows, en realidad acá http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php dice que solo hay que ejecutar el archivo X:\php\go-pear.bat pero parece ser viejo porque no tengo ese archivo.

También veo que se necesitan librerias adicionales: Boost, OpenSSL, y Protobuf.

En fin, espero que alguien pueda quitarme las dudas, gracias.

Comment: en la página pecl de la extensión hay un link que dice DLL (y un logo windows) ahi te lleva a las variantes compiladas para windows, te bajas el zip (x64 threadsafe supongo irá bien). adentro hay un dll que copias a la carpeta de extensiones (donde estan las otras extensiones ejemplo `c:\php\ext`) la agregas al php.ini y reinicias apache, phpinfo debería listarla. en el zip siempre hay un readme para detalles extra

Comment: Antes de instalar cualquier cosa, verifica primero si ya no lo tienes instalado. El Manual lo explica en el apartado [¿Dónde encontrar una extensión?](http://be2.php.net/manual/es/install.pecl.windows.php). En cuanto a los requisitos, si **vas a compilar la extensión**, [la doc de MySQL exige estos requisitos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysql-xdevapi.requirements.html), pero el Manual de PHP dice (primer enlace ^) que si instalas una extensión pre-compilada (DLL), no necesitas compilarla, como es lógico y en consecuencia esos requisitos no serían necesarios.

Comment: Los últimos DLL para Windows/PHP 7 [se encuentran aquí](https://pecl.php.net/package/mysql_xdevapi/8.0.11/windows), tendrías que descargar el de la versión 7.2, eligiendo entre Thread Safe o No Thread Safe.

Comment: Hola, descargué 'php_mysql_xdevapi-8.0.11-7.2-ts-vc15-x64. zip' y copie el archivo .dll a la carpeta de extensiones de PHP (ext), también añadí a php.ini la extensión en el apartado correspondiente (extension=mysql_xdevapi), y luego de reiniciar apache ya veo la extensión usando phpinfo().  Lo que ahora no estoy seguro es si debo instalar igual mas librerias boost y  protobufs, aca en este enlace lo dice : https://insidemysql.com/introducing-the-mysql-x-devapi-php-extension-for-mysql-8-0/ en la parte "install the php extension".